# Whats is the difference between 開発途上国 and 発展途上国?

Tags: word-choice, words, nuances

What is the difference in the usage of these 2 words?

I get the difference between 開発 and 発展 and my interpretation would be that 開発途上国 could refer to a developing country where the standard living conditions are low and are starting to improve, while 発展途上国 could refer to a country which is putting emphasis on infrastructure and other advancements.

Is one used a lot more over the other? Is there a minor difference in nuance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are identical. You can see [several dictionaries](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E9%96%8B%E7%99%BA%E9%80%94%E4%B8%8A%E5%9B%BD-42830#E3.83.87.E3.82.B8.E3.82.BF.E3.83.AB.E5.A4.A7.E8.BE.9E.E6.B3.89) redirecting 開発途上国 to 発展途上国. In that sense, 発展途上国 is somewhat more common.